# How do I vertically align this text in the center of the row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The children are just `<p>X</p>`.

I tried with `justify-content-center`, `align-items-center`, `text-center` but it doesn't work.

I want the text to be in the center of the square vertically and horizontally

HTML

```
<div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center boardRow">
   {[...Array(3).keys()].map((col, index_col) => (
      <div 
         className="d-flex flex-column d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center element innerBoard bg-danger">
         {children[row * 3 + col]} 
      </div>
   ))}
</div>
```

The css:

```
.boardBox {
  .element {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .boardRow:first-child .element {
    border-top: none;
  }
  .boardRow:last-child .element {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .boardRow .element:first-child {
    border-left: none;
  }
  .boardRow .element:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }
}

.innerBoard {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It could be that the `p` elements also include some bottom margin by default, so, they are centered including the margin. Try removing the margin from the paragraphs and see what happens

Comment: Replied so you can accept as correct answer and also help others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment above, the correct answer in case others face the same issue would be to take care of the `margin` that usually comes by default for most browsers for the `p` tags. Remove the `p` margin and everything should work ok.